# Regular Expression, detecting right characters

Tags: php, regex, expression, whitespace

I created this function that will allow me to send a string as a parameter, then I can choose wether id like to check for english, swedish or numbers. If it contains anything but the accepted characters function will return as false, else as true.

example:

```
$text = 'I like pancakes';  //This should return as true
if(isCharValid($text, 'english')) {
   die('returned as true');
}
else {
   die('returned as false');
}
```

However, Im having problem making the regex detect what Id like it to detect, you can see exactly what I want it to detect in the comments in the code.

This is my function

```
function isCharValid($string, $type){ 
    if($type == 'english') { //String may contain A-Z, a-z, 0-9 and whitespace
        return !preg_match('/[^A-Za-z0-9\s]/', $string);
    }
    else if($type == 'swedish'){ //String may contain A-Ö,a-ö,0-9 and whitespace
        return !preg_match('/[^A-Za-z0-9åäöÅÄÖ\s]/', $string);
    }
    else if($type == 'number'){ //String may contain numbers 0-9, no WHITESPACES
        return !preg_match('/[^0-9]*$/', $string);
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: It will always return `false` since you dont fill in your second parameter `$type`. If error reporting was turned on you would've seen a warning.

Answer (score 0):

You may require that the whole string should consist of these characters by enclosing the patterns with `^` / `$` and adding `+` quantifier to the *positive character classes*:

```
function isCharValid($string, $type){ 
    if($type == 'english') { //String may contain A-Z, a-z, 0-9 and whitespace
        return preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9\s]+$/u', $string);
    }
    else if($type == 'swedish'){ //String may contain A-Ö,a-ö,0-9 and whitespace
        return preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9åäöÅÄÖ\s]+$/u', $string);
    }
    else if($type == 'number'){ //String may contain numbers 0-9, no WHITESPACES
        return preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/Du', $string);
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then, use

```
$text = 'I like pancakes';  //This should return as true
$type = "english";
if(isCharValid($text, $type)) {
   die(returned as true);
}
else {
   die(returned as false);
}
```

Note that it is a good idea to add `/D` modifier to the last numeric regex to make sure a string with digits and a newline LF symbol at the end could not match.

Comment: No, it is not. The regexps require at least 1 char now, and only require what is allowed. Also, the `/u` is necessary since the texts are in Unicode.

Comment: Yes it is. He tests for a character outside the set, and then inverts the result with `!`. So it's the same test.

Comment: The only difference is requiring at least 1 character in the string. It's not clear that this is a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

call: `isCharValid($text,$type)`

instead of `isCharValid($text)`

Comment: Oh sorry, I do call the function like this in my code, just a brainfart in my example. Thansk for pointing it out :)